# Basic Prolog Error while generating a natural number

Tags: prolog

I am going back to prolog, and I'm trying to write a program that will generate all possible (integer) arrays of size X where each element is between A to B. For this, I began with generating all possible integers between A to B as follows:

```
iterate_number(Lower,Upper,Lower):= Lower =< Upper.
iterate_number(Lower,Upper,Rand):= Lower < Upper, Lower1 is Lower+1
                               , iterate_number(Lower1,Upper,Rand).
```

However, I got the error:

> ERROR: d:/test.pl:5:
> Full stop in clause-body?  Cannot redefine ,/2
> true

What exactly is wrong here? I thought maybe prolog has some problems with whitespaces in the *Lower1 is Lower+1* but it isn't the case. I'm surely missing something basic. What is it?

**Edit:** I tried to check for whitespace problem in the '<' and '=<', but nothing changed, still an error.

Comment: `s/:=/:-/` to begin with

Comment: You separate the head from the body with a colon (`:`) followed by a dash (`-`), so `:-`, not with `:=`.

Comment: Thanks. I figured it's something basic, but couldn't find what it is. Thanks!